# Как сделать нестандартную рамку?

Tags: html, css

Как задать такую рамку как на скрине?

[image]

Чтобы была сверху в виде стрелки, угла (не знаю как еще сказать).
Bот рабочий пример - `//codepen.io/anon/pen/xGMwQo`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

С помощью псевдоэлементов `:before` и `:after`.
Пример не идеальный, но уже от него можно продолжать копать.

```css
.unusual {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.unusual img {
  border: 4px solid blue;
  width: 400px;
}

.unusual:before,
.unusual:after {
  position: absolute;
  top: -14%;
  content: '';
  display: block;
  border: 4px solid blue;
  width: 60%;
  height: 30%;
  background: white;
}

.unusual:before {
  left: -15%;
  transform: rotate(-30deg);
}

.unusual:after {
  right: -15%;
  transform: rotate(30deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="unusual">
  <img src="http://static.jsbin.com/images/dave.min.svg">
</div>
```